# Add default value in Rails after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, `Desk` and `Type`. Desk belongs to Type. Type has 2 `type_size`: small and large.

Desk has 2 columns, `width` and `length`.

I would like to add default dimensions depending on the type.

I tried this in my `Desk` model:

```
before_validation :add_dimensions, on: :create

private
def add_dimensions
  if self.type.type_size == 'small'
    self.width = 40
    self.length = 50
  else
    self.width = 60
    self.length = 80
  end
end
```

But this doesn't work, i tried to change `before_validation` to `after_create` or something similar and I got `Stack level too deep`

What is the best way to set default dimensions?

Comment: add this method in before_create  :add_dimensions .

Comment: @Vishal i tried but it doesn't do anything, how do i check if the function is being called?

Comment: Try to debug your code  there is one excellent gem available for debugging in ruby, `gem pry` install this gem in your application. then you can simply write `binding.pry` in your method `add_dimensions`  so when this method call, the server will be in debug mode and you can check all your values of self and etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use before_create:

```
before_create :add_dimensions

private
def add_dimensions
  if self.type.type_size == 'small'
    self.width = 40
    self.length = 50
  else
    self.width = 60
    self.length = 80
  end
end
```

Or you can use before_save on new_record like:

```
before_save :add_dimensions, :if => :new_record?

private
def add_dimensions
  if self.type.type_size == 'small'
    self.width = 40
    self.length = 50
  else
    self.width = 60
    self.length = 80
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and it works when I do `Desk.create` in console, but it still doesn't get picked up when i do it on the website